# LinkedIn V2 version /me API returns permission error

Tags: linkedin-api

Does anyone able make call to LinkedIn V2/me version using linkedin OAuth endpoints, with the auth code flow.

I could get the authorization code and could exchange it with the valid access token. Using the token I am able to successfully call /userinfo endpoint.
However, /me API returns "Not enough permissions to access /me GET".

I could get the authorization code and could exchange it with the valid access token. Using the token I am able to successfully call /userinfo endpoint.